# getElementById with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to get my links to enable their respective buttons.  For instance the first link should enable the first button and the second should enable button 2.

Can anyone help?

```
<a href="http://www.linkhere.com" onclick="document.getElementById("butt1").disabled=false">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://www.linkhere.com" onclick="document.getElementById("butt2").disabled=false">Link 2</a>

   <button disabled class="btn btn-primary pull-left" id="butt1">Button 1</button>
   <button disabled class="btn btn-primary pull-left" id="butt2">Button 2</button>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("butt1")` should be `document.getElementById('butt1')`. Same goes for `butt2`. Also, use developer tools available is every browser when you debug javascript.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is your use of quotation marks. There are two options:

1. Use single quotes
2. Use `&quot;` or `\22` instead of your double quotes

**Explanation**

Your `onclick` is wrapped in double quotes. As soon as you use a double quote, it's the end of the `onclick`.

**Solution**

```
<a href="http://www.linkhere.com" onclick="document.getElementById('butt1').disabled=false">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://www.linkhere.com" onclick="document.getElementById(&quot;butt2&quot;).disabled=false">Link 2</a>
```

**Demonstration**

See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nofjcnbv/1/) (Thanks @JamesThorpe for updating the escaped quote option)

Note, I removed the href because it doesn't make sense to link somewhere if you're going to do something on the current page.

Comment: @DavidThomas You need to take the spaces out of the calls to `getElementById`

Comment: @James: thank you! For some reason that hadn't occurred to me >_< and, jcuenod, in your linked Fiddle the second link is resulting in `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`.

Comment: Yes - the escaping should be `&quot;`, not `\"`

Comment: @JamesThorpe ahh, right - but I can't seem to get that to work (or `\x22` or even `\\\`)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `"butt*"` with `'butt*'` , otherwise the browser read this

```
onclick="document.getElementById("
```

and edit the `href="link"` with `href="#"` (this is not mandatory, but the question as it is now is a little strange)

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('butt1').disabled=false">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('butt2').disabled=false">Link 2</a>

<button disabled class="btn btn-primary pull-left" id="butt1">Button 1</button>
<button disabled class="btn btn-primary pull-left" id="butt2">Button 2</button>
```

Comment: Why edit the `href`? That changes the function of the code in question.

Comment: @RGraham with a link in href the onclick function is not performed

Comment: @WhiteLine Not true. The action is performed before the browser loads the `href`

Comment: @RGraham: but surely that negates the point of enabling the `<button>`? I realise it's what the OP wrote, but...seems silly, really; unless the action is prevented somewhere else.

Comment: @RGraham yes, but it makes no sense to do so.

Comment: It is possible that the OP has simplified the code for the sake of the question (for example removing `target="_blank"` from the links). Or the href values are there in case the browser has JavaScript disabled.

Comment: In any case `href="#"` makes the page scroll to top which is unlikely to be wanted.

Comment: @DavidThomas The intent of this is usually to prevent double-submission, or to stop the user performing an action while the next URL is loading. Not silly at all :)

Answer (score 1):

`removeAttribute(:attribute)` can do the trick as well.

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('butt1').removeAttribute('disabled');">Link 1</a>
<button disabled class="btn btn-primary pull-left" id="butt1">Button 1</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the quatation marks for the id from double to single ones:

```
document.getElementById('butt1').disabled=false;
```

If the anchor is just for the activation, add an return false at the end:

```
document.getElementById('butt1').disabled=false; return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

you problem in this string

```
"document.getElementById("butt1").disabled=false"
```

it should be

```
"document.getElementById('butt1').disabled=false"
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/urLpjLbk/) here

Answer (score 0):

With a bit more work you start enabling a bit more elements, or add functionality that you could expand on easier in the future.

As a simple example, i added a small javascript file where you could set the elements that upon click activate/deactivate the other elements.

Currently i am preventing the default action, so you wouldn't be navigating towards the link you are actually setting, but that is entirely up to you ;)

```js
;(function (ns) {
  
  var actionElements = {
      l1: ['butt1'],
      l2: ['butt2']
    };
  
  function bootstrap() {
    var prop, value, element;
    for (prop in actionElements) {
      if (actionElements.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        element = document.getElementById(prop);
        value = actionElements[prop];
        if (element) {
          element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            if (typeof e === 'undefined') {
              var e = window.event;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
              var el = document.getElementById(this[i]);
              el.disabled = false;
            }
            return false;
          }.bind(value));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  ns.addEventListener('load', bootstrap);
  
}(window));
```

```html
<a href="http://www.linkhere.com" id="l1">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://www.linkhere.com" id="l2">Link 2</a>

<button disabled class="btn btn-primary pull-left" id="butt1">Button 1</button>
<button disabled class="btn btn-primary pull-left" id="butt2">Button 2</button>
```